# Component Components are not displayed on the page how to fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

**I have a blocks generator**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";
import React from 'react';


const GameName = []
const GameValueType = []
const GamePrice = []
const GameImg = []
const GameDesc = []

const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: "---",
    authDomain: "---",
    databaseURL: "---",
    projectId: "---",
    storageBucket: "---",
    messagingSenderId: "---",
    appId: "---"
});

export default app;


const database = getDatabase()
const shop = ref(database, '/games')
export function data(){
    onValue(shop,(snapshot) =>{
        const gamesInfo = snapshot.val()
        for (let key in gamesInfo){
            GamePrice.push(gamesInfo[key]["price"])
            GameValueType.push(gamesInfo[key]["currency_type"])
            GameName.push(gamesInfo[key]["Name"])
            GameImg.push(gamesInfo[key]["ImgUrl"])
            GameDesc.push(gamesInfo[key]["Desc"])
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < GameName.length;i++){
            const CardBlockFront = document.createElement("div")
            const CardBlock = document.createElement("div")
            const CardName = document.createElement("div")
            const CardPrice = document.createElement("div")
            const CardDesc = document.createElement("div")
            const CardBlockBack = document.createElement("div")
            const CardFlipper = document.createElement("div")

            CardBlockFront.setAttribute("class", `front`)
            CardBlock.setAttribute("class", "flip-container")
            CardFlipper.setAttribute("class", "flipper")
            CardBlockBack.setAttribute("class","back")
            CardBlockFront.setAttribute("style", "background-image: url(" + GameImg[i] + ");background-repeat: no-repeat;background-size: cover" )

            CardPrice.innerHTML = GamePrice[i] + " " + GameValueType[i]
            CardName.innerHTML = GameName[i]
            CardDesc.innerHTML = GameDesc[i]
            CardBlockBack.append(CardName,CardPrice,CardDesc)
            CardFlipper.append(CardBlockFront,CardBlockBack)
            CardBlock.append(CardFlipper)

            document.getElementById("ShopCards").appendChild(CardBlock)

        }
        console.log(GameName)
    })
}
data()
```

**which adds elements here**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GetAndPastData from "../Components/GetAndPastData.js";

class Shop extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <h2 className={"text-center m-4"}>Games</h2>
                    <h2 className={"text-center m-4"}>Buying server is closed </h2>
                    <div className={"m-4"} id="ShopCards">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
}
}
export default Shop;
```

**And Routed in Headers.js**

```
export default function Headers (){

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
    const handleClose = () => setShow(false)
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true)

    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark")
    const  themeToggle = () => {
        theme === "light" ? setTheme("dark") : setTheme("light")
    };

    return(
            <>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme === "light" ? lightTheme : darkTheme}>
                <GlobalStyles/>
                <SyledApp>
                <Router>
                <Navbar fixed={"top"} id={"MS"} collapseOnSelect expand={"md"} bg={"dark"} variant={"dark"} className={"MainSite"}>
                    <Button variant={"info"} className={"me-sm-3"} onClick={()=> themeToggle()}>change theme</Button>
                    <Container>
                        <Navbar.Brand className={"SiteName"} as={Link} to={"/"}>
                            <img
                                src = {logo}
                                height={"30"}
                                width={"30"}
                                className={"d-inline-block align-top"}
                                alt ={"Logo"}
                            /> DpGame
                        </Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls={"responsive-navbar-nav"} />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id={"responsive-navbar-nav"}>
                            <Nav className={"me-auto"}>
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/about"} >About us</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/contacts"} >Contacts</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link as={Link} to={"/shop"}  >Shop</Nav.Link>
                            </Nav>
                        <Form className={"d-flex"}>
                            <FormControl
                                type={"text"}
                                placeholder="Search (didnt work yet)"
                                className={"me-sm-2"}
                            />
                            <Button variant={"outline-info"}>Search</Button>
                        </Form>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Container>
                <Form className={"d-flex me-sm-2"}>
                    <Button variant={"info"} className={"me-sm-3"} onClick={handleShow}>Sing Up</Button>
                    <Button variant={"outline-info"} onClick={handleShow}>Log In</Button>
                </Form>
            </Navbar>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path={"/"} element={<Home />}/>
                    <Route path={"/about"} element={<About />}/>
                    <Route path={"/contacts"} element={<Contacts />}/>
                    <Route path={"/shop"}  element={<Shop />}/>
                </Routes>
            </Router>
```

The problem is that only when I refresh the page, these blocks are generated, but if I move to it from another page, they do not appear. I roughly understand why. But how to fix it I do not know. Please help .I am new in React.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what the code is trying to do. Can you provide a more complete and cohesive [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? From what I see the blocks are created and directly appended to the DOM, completely outside of React, so React doesn't know to rerender the app.

Comment: Yes, I think it's like you said, is there any way to get these blocks rendered in react?

Comment: Maybe. That is why I asked for a more complete code example so we can see how all the code relates. Best I can tell is something in the `Shop` component is supposed to be generating the blocks, but the React trail goes dead there. What is calling the blocks generator code, what is calling `onValue` to create this content?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the blocks themselves are transferred to Shop through the usual import, without functions and so on, just "import GetAndPastData from "./Components/GetAndPastData.js";". And the contents of the blocks are firebase database

Comment: Yes, I see that a `GetAndPastData` is imported in the `Shop` component. Then what? Is it used anywhere?

Comment: No, it doesn't, I did a function in it but when I added it, it was duplicated, I don't know why. So I left it that way and it stopped duplicating.

Comment: *What* is duplicating? What function are you referring to? I think the piece we're missing here is the function that is generating the blocks/content, and where in React you want this to happen.

Comment: My goal is to generate blocks, and insert them into the shop. 
All of the code I've inserted is all I have from this chain, excluding app.js which just displays Headers.

Comment: Ah, I see, so `document.getElementById("ShopCards")` in the `onValue` function is "injecting" these created DOM elements into the `<div className={"m-4"} id="ShopCards" />` element in `Shop`. Is `onValue` just called somewhere in `GetAndPastData`? Can you supply the rest of the contents of that file? I think you just need to convert from manually creating DOMNodes to rendering JSX within the `Shop` component. If this isn't feasible then you'll need to expose the function that is creating the elements to `Shop` so it can create them upon mounting, and trigger a state update so it rerenders.

Comment: i add full GetAndPastData file

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The main issue with the existing code is that it:

1. Directly mutates the DOM, an anti-pattern in React
2. Doesn't trigger any state update in react to trigger React to rerender to update the view

## Solution

I suggest moving all the `data` function's logic into the `Shop` component. Save the fetched data into local React state. Use `componentDidMount` to instantiate the data fetching, and render the state to JSX.

Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getDatabase, ref, onValue} from "firebase/database";
import GetAndPastData from "../Components/GetAndPastData.js";

class Shop extends Component {
  state = {
    games: [],
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const database = getDatabase();
    const shop = ref(database, '/games');

    onValue(shop, snapshot => {
      const gamesInfo = snapshot.val();
      const games = [];
      gamesInfo.forEach(game => {
        games.push({
          Desc: game.Desc,
          ImgUrl: game.ImgUrl,
          Name: game.Name,
          price: game.price,
          currency_type: game.currency_type,
        });
      });
      this.setState({ games });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2 className={"text-center m-4"}>Games</h2>
        <h2 className={"text-center m-4"}>Buying server is closed </h2>
        <div className={"m-4"} id="ShopCards">
          {games.map(game => (
            <div key={game.name} className="flip-container">
              <div className="flipper">
                <div 
                  className="front"
                  style={{
                    backgroundImage: `url("${game. ImgUrl}")`,
                    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                    backgroundSize: "cover"
                  }}
                />
                <div className="back">
                  <div>{game.Name}</div>
                  <div>{game.price} {game.currency_type}</div>
                  <div>{game.Desc}</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: src\Pages\Shop.js
  Line 38:22:  'games' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

React gives me this error. Also firebase needs those keys that are contained in const app, I hide them because firebase tells me they are private.

Comment: and when i call a gameInfo[key]["Name"] The program accesses the database, with the "Name" key, and takes there the values of that key "Name".

Comment: @Bester I don't know what `Shop.js:38:22` is in your code, but did you miss declaring a `games` array to push values into from the snapshot? The keys can be named for whatever you need for your specific use case, the code above is an example refactoring.